# Warning JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: xml, joomla, find, warnings

When i trying to Upload com_jconverter_v0.3.zip Package File not working 
show this error

Warning

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Comment: please help me how i can resolve this issue

Comment: what version Joomla are you using and when you open the XML file, what version is defined on line 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, You check your joomla website version and also check your template version.
And now still those error,create index.html and put in template folder and only 
this - 
`<html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></body></html>` is in index.html file. now again upload template agian,

i hope this is help for you for solve JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file